# Ubuntu 18.04 and cifs/smb shares missing in file>open dialog boxes

Tags: 18.04, samba, cifs, dialog

I've been using ubuntu since 8.04 but have only recently been working with 18.04. I usually stay one LTS behind. I installed handbrake and gigolo. I have bookmarks in my file browser sidebar and can access my samba shares from my Synology without a problem. The issue is that when I open up handbrake and try to open a file from a network share, the share's aren't available in the file>open dialog. I can't manually navigate to them via the gvfs folders either because it doesn't like the permissions situation for /run. Sooooo.... I'm sure there is a trivial way to enable this but I haven't found it. Oh, and also, the Connect to Server's 'connect' button stays grayed out no matter what I type in there.
Fresh install, up to date, VM on ESXi
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are permissions on `/run/` directory?

Comment: permissions for /run/ : drwxr-xr-x

Answer (score 0):

Which handbrake did you install? There are 2 in "Ubuntu Software".

One is a snap labeled handbrake-jz. Try as I might I cannot get to the gvfs mount point for my network share.

The other is labeled HandBrake. It comes from the Ubuntu repository. This one allows me to access the mount point. In fact it shows up on the side panel of the "Open Source" dialog in HandBrake.

They are at different levels however. jz is at 1.2 and the repository one is 1.1

**EDIT**: This one I didn't test but there is also a PPA with instructions on how to install it for this app that I think is at version 1.3 here: https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/ubuntu/handbrake-releases

Comment: Yup, I discovered all this myself earlier today, I was going to jump on here and share right after work. THANKS!!!!!